# Is it possible to center-align a block of inline, left-aligned <div>s?

Tags: html, css, layout

Building my first website, and learning HTML, CSS, PHP, MySQL as needed.  I'd like a set of inline divs which are aligned to the left.  However, if there's not enough room to fill the screen, I'd like for the entire block of inline divs to be centered.  After much searching and research, I determined it was impossible with only CSS, due to the fact that the internal size of all the inline left aligned divs would have to be calculated before the auto margin of the centered containing div could be calculated.  I ended up kludging it together with the use of a whole bunch of invisible inline "ghost" divs which make the last line of the inline divs appear as if it's left-aligned.

Now it looks like this, which is great. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmru7.png

I gave the fake divs a border, and now they're visible. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmru7.png

Firstly, is there an elegant solution to this aside from media tags which change the CSS depending on screen size?  Secondly, is it possible to force it to center when there's only one line?

i.stack.imgur.com/ DjWaj.png

CSS: (stripped, if something seems missing let me know)

```
div.pmegaframe {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto; padding: 0px; 
    text-align: center; }

div.pfake {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 22px; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px;
    width: 164px; height: 1;
    border: none; }

div.pframe {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 15px;
    width: 164px;
    border: 6px solid var(--header); }
/*div.pframe:hover {
    border: 16px solid #B85843; }*/

div.pminiframe {
    width: 160px; 
    margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
    border: 2px solid var(--white); 
    background: var(--dark); }

div.pimageframe {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 160px; height: 160px; 
    color: var(--accent);
    background: var(--white); }

div.pwordsframe {
    position: relative;
    width: 160px; height: 280px; }
```

index.php (stripped)

```
<div class="pmegaframe">

        <?php
            $pquery = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT f_name, l_name, blurb FROM users"); 
            $pnum = mysqli_num_rows($pquery); $id = 0; //Pull userdata 

            while ($id < $pnum) { //Collect userdata
                mysqli_data_seek($pquery, $id); $prow = mysqli_fetch_row($pquery);
                $image = "160px_profile_".$id; $name = $prow[0]." ".$prow[1];
                $text = $prow[2];
                $state = 0; $rating = 1;

                $squery = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT ID, courseID FROM subjects WHERE userID=".$id); //Pull the user's subjects
                $snum = mysqli_num_rows($squery);

                include "pframe.php"; //Makes the userframe

                $id += 1; 
            }

        echo str_repeat("<div class=\"pfake\"></div>", 8); 
            //fills in the grid with invisible boxes 
        ?>

    </div>
```

pframe.php (also stripped):

```
<div class="pframe"> <!--The base grey outer frame-->
    <a href="profile.php?user=<?php print $id?>" class="nocolor"> <!-- links it-->
        <div class="pminiframe"> <!-- puts down the interior white frame-->
            <div class="pimageframe"> <!--The upper half of the box-->
                <img src="/profiles/<?php echo $image; ?>.png" alt="Profile image not found!"></div>
            <div class="pwordsframe"> <!--The lower half of the box-->
                <!-- *snip*  This was the messy content of the lower half of the profile boxes. -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You may want to rethink your design or you'll have a tough time making your page look good on mobile devices and larger screens (if you care).  Have you looked into Bootstrap? http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Mobile devices actually show quite well.  Larger screens, however, are what I am concerned about.  Code upcoming.

Comment: Here's a decent tutorial on Bootstrap basics: http://www.codecademy.com/skills/make-a-website/topics/bootstrap-components

Comment: i think @media tags are the elegant solution?

Comment: @Rusty: the difficulty is that the boxes are eventually going to have variable width, leading me back to the same issue of having to know the interior div's size before I can calculate the properties of the containing div.